# Why can't a count noun denote a class when used alone without any determiner?

Tags: nouns

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 335) says:

> A count noun denotes a class of individuated entities of the same kind. *Boy*, for example, denotes the class of boys.

For example, in (1) the count noun *boy* denotes the class of boys but is combined with *A* to denote an individuated entity. And the same is true with the count noun *human*.

> (1) *A boy is a young male human.*

But when used alone (without any determiner such as *a*), as in (2), the count nouns *boy* and *human* cannot seem to denote the class:

> (2) **Boy is young male human.*

Why is that?

(Although this is a *why* question, I hope this is detailed enough to be answerable.)

Comment: Because English.

Comment: Count nouns in the singular form would require an article.  And yes, as pointed out above, it is just that way.

Comment: Just to confuse matters more (why not?), add a comma and "Boy is young, male human" is a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: @Spencer I couldn't care less about more confusion, if necessary. Are you sure the sentence with a comma is correct? Please explain how adding a comma makes the difference.

Comment: @JK2 Because the meanings change. It is NOT the meaning the sentence in the question is trying to convey. "Boy" becomes a proper noun and "male human" becomes a direct address.   The sentence is unlikely to ever be heard except in the movie _Tarzan versus the Aliens_.

Comment: @Spencer Thanks for your comments, but I don't think your example confuses anything. Proper nouns and vocatives do not denote a class. Only common nouns do. CGEL's description of count nouns is limited to common nouns.

Comment: @JK2 It was a joke......

Comment: But you ***can*** say “*Boy* is another name for *young male human*”

Comment: And if we were arguing about what was what in a Venn diagram and you said “We should add “the elements of Boy to the elements of “Young male human”  I might say, “No, Boy ***is*** young male human.”

Comment: @Jim That's the old mention versus usage dodge!

Comment: *Dog* can totally denote a class of *meat*. *Cottage* can totally denote a class of *cheese*. My instinct would be that a count noun with no determiner can totally denote a class of an uncountable thing, it's just that *humans* in their own right are countable already. So every sub-category has to be countable, too. (Except that — as indeed my very own examples show — we might need to dig deeper and work on a more bulletproof wording than the one I've just chosen. But yeah, *boy* can certainly denote a class of *meat*. Now you.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a constraint on the well-formedness of English noun phrases that an NP with a singular count noun as Head (of the nominal), must have an overt Determiner. Consider:

- What's this?
- *Pen (ungrammatical)

And then compare this with:

- What's this?
- A/my/Bob's/some/the pen. (grammatical!)

So, in short, it is not that in the string *Boy is young male human*, the word *boy* cannot represent the class of boys. Rather, it's the case that the string is not well formed and is therefore uninterpretable.

Of course, nouns occur mainly in noun phrases. Noun phrases are complex, and like other types of phrases can often be thought of as constructions. [It is only once a noun enters into a construction in some way that we can give it a salient interpretation](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Notice that when CamGEL refer to *Boy* in that quote they are referring to the lexeme *boy* not the singular uninflected form of the noun in particular.

Comment: If it's really about a constraint on the well-formedness of English noun phrases that an NP with a singular count noun as Head (of the nominal), must have an overt Determiner, why is it that you can say _Man is a political animal._ and not _A man is a political animal._ or _The man is a political animal._? Do you think _man_ is an exception or _boy_ is an exception?

Comment: @JK2 *Man* is a proper noun there.

Comment: _Man_ is capitalized not because it's a proper noun but because it's the first word in the sentence. For example, you can say _I think man is a political animal_, where _man_ is not capitalized. Not all capitalized nouns are proper nouns, but all proper nouns are capitalized. And I know of no dictionary or grammar that claims that _man_ in this sense is a proper noun. Do you?

Comment: @JK2 The capitalisation is irrelevant. Incidentally, it's just a peverse fact that we use capitals for kingdoms, phyla etc, etc, but not species. Still proper nouns as far as I can tell (compare with the Latin counterparts *homo sapiens* etc). However, if I'm wrong (don't think I am), it makes no odds really. That would just be a freaky exception. Note that *man* has a completely different meaning here (for example, has nothing to do with maleness). This constraint is well-known and well-discussed.

Comment: @JK2 So, basically, not the same lexeme.

Comment: But you haven't answer my question yet: "Do you know of any dictionary or grammar that claims that _man_ in this sense is a proper noun?" If there's any, I'd be glad to take a look at it. Unless and until you find me such a dictionary or grammar, let's just say it's a common noun. I think _man_ was used to represent the human race, both male and female, in the past because females were considered subservient to males.

Comment: @JK2 Erm, no let's not.! I've got a better suggestion. Why don't you have a look at the grammatical evidence and try and make some kind of argument that it is a common count noun? And, please, let's never, evet suggest referring to dictionaries for grammatical information!

Comment: @JK2 That makes no difference. Synchronically, it's a different lexeme.

Comment: I said, "...a dictionary **or grammar**...". What's your definition of a proper noun?

Comment: @JK2 And I said "let's never, ever suggest referring to dictionaries for grammatical information!". I also said " ...  look at the grammatical evidence and try and make some kind of argument that it is a common count noun" ; -)

Comment: If you had claimed that the _man_ was a common non-count noun, it could have been less confusing. Like I said, I do not know of any such authoritative source, be it a grammar or a linguistics paper, and apparently neither do you. Then, is it just a figment of your imagination? I don't object to using your own imagination as a basis for classifying _man_ as a proper noun, but you need to present your own definition of a proper noun, at the very least.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore - Re your comments to JK2, saying that "man" in "Man is a political animal" is a proper noun and that that is "well-discussed and well-known", can you suggest any linguistics papers, articles, etc. on this subject? I haven't been able to find any. To me, personally, this usage of *man* seems extremely similar to the usages, "the orangutan/ tiger/ venus flytrap/ etc." - the only crucial difference being the absence of the definite article with *man*.